# fatal error: index out of range tableview with two sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to populate a tableView with 2 sections using two arrays of Firebase objects (called snapshots). I'm getting an error in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function when I try to load the tableView: `fatal error: Index out of range`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PersonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PersonCell

  //set cell text
  let guardianDict = guardians[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject] // error happens here
  let dependentDict = dependents[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject]

  cell.personName.text = "test"

  return cell
}
```

Here is how I define my sections:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch(section){
            case 0: return "Dependents"

            case 1: return "Guardians"

        default: return ""
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

EDIT: Adding the numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        switch(section){
        case 0: return self.dependents.count

        case 1: return self.guardians.count

        default: return 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you have for the rest of your `UITableViewDataSource` implementation? Specifically `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSections`? That's where the the `indexPath` values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` come from. Also, the sections will be zero-indexed so you will have to use `case 0` and `case 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Fixed the zero-indexing. Added the sections you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two sections in your table with each section coming from different sources. You need to add checking in your cellForRowIndexPath function to access the right array:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PersonCell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PersonCell

  if indexPath.section == 0
  {
    let dependentDict = dependents[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject]
  }
  else if indexPath.section == 1
  {
    let guardianDict = guardians[indexPath.row].value as! [String :  AnyObject] // error happens here
  }
  cell.personName.text = "test"

  return cell
}
```

Comment: That worked! That logic makes perfect sense. This is my first time trying to load data from multiple source into multiple sections. I wasn't aware it was so easy to check sections like that! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your two arrays may be of different sizes, so in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to check which section you are returning a cell for and only access the appropriate array.  Currently you are accessing both arrays for each call to this function, resulting in index out of range exceptions when one of the arrays is smaller than the other.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PersonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PersonCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let dependentDict = dependents[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject]
        cell.personName.text = dependentDict["name"] as! String //Or whatever element in the dictionary is needed
    } else {
        let guardianDict = guardians[indexPath.row].value as! [String : AnyObject] 
        cell.personName.text = guardianDict["name"] as! String //Or whatever element in the dictionary is needed
    }

    return cell
}
```